# Google search: how can I get as many results as possible (instead of default 10)

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-search-appliance

My organization has an internal google appliance search server and I am able to get search results in XML via the following form:

```
<form method="get" action="http://internal-google-appliance-server/search">
        <input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="btnG" value="Search">
          <input type="hidden" name="site" value="my-searchindex">
        <input type="hidden" name="output" value="xml_no_dtd">
</form>
```

However, this returns a maximum of 10 search results.

I would like to know what  hidden input I can add in order to get as many results as possible.

To my knowledge, this server allows so.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `num`.

> Maximum number of results to include in the search results. The maximum value of this parameter is 1000. Taken together, the values of the start and num parameters determine the range of the results that are returned.
>
> The initial index point of the search results is the value of the start parameter. The ending index point of the search results is the value of the start parameter plus the value of the num parameter minus 1. All index points are zero based, meaning the first result has the value 0.
>
> The actual number of results may be smaller than the requested value.

Source: https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/614/xml_reference#request_parameters

Answer (score 0):

Also the parameter filter=0 in addition to num=1000 might help.